# Populate a memory array of 64K words – each word is 20 bits wide – out of 1K by 4 bit memory chips. How many such chips will you need?

Tags: bit

I know this doesn't exactly fit the mold of this site, but this is a better place to ask than say Yahoo Answers. Can anyone help me with this?

Suppose you are instructed to populate a memory array of 64K words – where each word is 20 bits wide (let’s assume the extra 4 bits are for error correction) – out of 1K by 4 bit memory chips.  How many such chips will you need?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the assumtion is wrong. If the word is define as 20 bits don't assume that it must be contained in a multiple of 8 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a guess :-)

24bits/word, 65536 words = 1572864 bits.

1K x 4-bit memory means 4096 bits/chip, is that correct?

Then we have 1572864 bits / 4096 bits/chip = 384 chips.

Comment: I think you are right... but what about parts B and C: b. How many address bits will go directly to the memory chips?
c. How many address bits will need to be decoded before being routed to the individual memory chips?

Comment: Do I just need a power of 2 > 384 for part b? or is that part c? I find this question really confusing.

Comment: If you have 384 chips, you need 9 bits to address them (2 ^ 9 = 512).

Comment: And then, I suppose, you'll have to decode 16 bits to get the address of the correct chip, because you can't just process 9 bits.

Answer (score 0):

5x 1Kx4 chips for 1K words, so 5*64 chips in total is 320